# How to connect Laravel 5.4 backend with Angular 5 Frontend

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel, angular5

I am working on a project where I need to develop frontend in angular 5 and backend business logic in laravel 5.4 with mySql Database. I am a newbie to this technology and dont know how to develop data flow connection between these two framworks.

It will be helpful if you tell me the easiest and most generic way to solve this out.

Comment: watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtklHQUfNZQ&list=PLe30vg_FG4OSbizS6Gpw_LICp9zBcmjZU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any other technology, you'll need to work with an API.

**In your Laravel project:**

Your Laravel project should have models, controllers and a file for the route paths for each method in your controllers, right? If you don't know where the routes are, there's a dedicated folder called "routes" at the root of your project.

Inside this folder, you'll have two important files: api.php and web.php. These two work exactly the same way, but the api.php will automatically add '/api' to the beginning of your route.

A route looks like a link, such as: "yourdomain.com/api/person/name/jondoe". Every route has to be accessed through an HTTP method, usually GET, POST, PUT or DELETE.

Example: let's say you need your user to see a list of people. You'll probably have a Person model and a PersonController containing some function called displayAllPeople(), and this function will select the people from your database. In your api.php file you'll add something like:

Route::get('/people', 'PersonController@displayAllPeople');

You can test that in your browser. Try to access http://yourdomain.com/api/people. You should see a JSON output of your function's return data. In this example, a list of people. Now all we have to do is make your Angular project call this API route.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers

**In your Angular project:**

Remember that Person model you created on your backend? Angular will access that model too, so you'll have to create a Person.ts model here. While that's not required to work, it's a good practice to create this model with the same attributes as the backend model.

Now you'll need a service. The service is a file that will access that Laravel route for you. If you're using Angular CLI, just run the command:

```
ng generate service person
```

That will create a person.service.ts file for you. Inside this file, you'll write all the functions to select people, update, save, delete people, and so on. Your function will look something like this:

```
findAll(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return this.http.get<Person[]>('yourdomain.com/api/people');
}
```

Whenever you call the findAll() function, you'll access the Laravel route, which will return the People from your database. You can do that with any operation you want. Just make sure you follow the HTTP standards.

That also works if you want to send some data from your frontend to the backend, like if you want to save some new Person in your database. You'll need a POST call sending your new Person model which will be received by your Laravel's Controller function, and then persist it in the database.

Source: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Thank You For such a detailed over view and your time, I will try this and if find any issue I will ask from you further sir.

Comment: sir please help me out I am stuck.